# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException error in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and I have a problem. I'm trying to delete values form web page (values display form database to webpage) but one error occur that is

```
http://Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
…\bootstrap\compiled.php5726
```

An error code is throw new `NotFoundHttpException();`

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the route you're looking at exists in your routes.php file. You can also do this through the command line using `$ php artisan routes` You can narrow it down with say: `$ php artisan routes | grep 'route_name'`

Then check the route isn't behind a conditional filter. For example if you're using user log-in etc, make sure the route you're after isn't within an authenticated route group.

Answer (score 0):

This is just Laravel's way of saying "404, file not found" - no route matches the URL (and request method) you're accessing (most likely - maybe you've got a `GET` route but you're doing a `POST`?), or your code is doing `App::abort(404)` somewhere (less likely).

Comment: oute::group(array('prefix' =>'/newsandevents'),function()
{Route::delete('/newsandevents/delete',array('uses'=>'NewsandeventsController@delete','as'=>'delete'));
}); my routes.php

Comment: @CNB `Route::delete` requires following the special instructions at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form because browsers don't support the `DELETE` method. Can you show us your `Form::open` tag?

Comment: {{Form::open('newsandevents/delete','DELETE',array('style'=>'display:inline'))}}
{{Form::hidden('id',$newsevents->id)}}
{{Form::submit('delete')}}
{{Form::close()}} is my tag..

Comment: @CNB Well, that's your problem. `Form::open` takes a single parameter, an array, as clearly indicated in the linked documentation. Try `Form::open(['url' => 'newsandevents/delete', 'method' => 'delete', 'style' => 'display:inline']);` If you view source you should see that your current approach isn't adding the `method` hidden input nor the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and it was caused by my route calling the `delete` method on my controller instead of `destroy`.